# Receiving Response Code 502 from Google Custom Search JSON API

Tags: google-custom-search

I am making HTTP request to Google Custom Search as specified in Documentation here
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/cse/list

A couple of days ago everything was working fine, however, now search API returns 502 ERROR sporadically. Most of the search requests go thru but some return generic "That's an error" page

Is anybody else getting this?

Is anybody aware if there is a status page for Google Custom Search JSON service?

Here is the response body from JSON API

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
 <meta charset=utf-8>
 <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
 <title>Error 502 (Server Error)!!1</title>
 <style>
   {margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px} > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
 </style>
 <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
 <p><b>502.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
 <p>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

Comment: We are getting a lot of these, too. Wonder what's happening at Google's end.

Answer (score 2):

We've been having the exact same issue in the past couple of days using the .NET client and it definitely seems to be on Google's side.
I "solved" this by adding a retry mechanism. When listRequest.Execute().Items fails, I catch the exception, sleep for a second and retry. So far is the only thing that worked.

Comment: that's not a bad idea. But it seems that this may have been addressed already, haven't received this error in past 10 hours.

Comment: @lev thanks for letting me know. I'll check if this is happening but keep the retry code just in case.